# Cannot find entry symbol _start

Tags: gcc

My c code on compiling on gcc is giving the error `Cannot find entry symbol _start defaulting to 00000`. Can anyone tell me why and how to correct it?

The command line is `arm-none-eabi-gcc -O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -mfloat-abi=softfp file path` and the target platform is a-8 sitara cortex processor.

Comment: You need to post more info. Especially your command line and target platform.

Comment: the command line is arm-none-eabi-gcc  -O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -mfloat-abi=softfp file path and the target platform is a-8 sitara cortex processor

Comment: `_start` is part of standard library. It's the function which calls `main`. It should be defined in `crt0.o` which should be automatically linked with your program. It is possible that your gcc works differently and requires some additional actions. Maybe there are some working examples in the documentation?

Comment: Add a "-###" as your first argument and post the output, i.e. "arm-none-eabi-gcc -### -O3 -march=armv7 ..."

Comment: It might be because your c program is not having main() function in it. Please post your c program.

Answer (score 9):

The only reason the compiler threw the above error is because the start code(_start function) generated by the OS for running your code cannot find the default or registered function main.  So either you can use _start function instead of main function but the compilation command should be gcc -nostartfiles filename.c but using _start there are a lot of exceptions so better to use main instead.

Answer (score 7):

the -none- part means that your toolchain doesn't build for a particular operating system, so you must define a _start entry point.  For non-bare-metal toolchains that build for a particular operating system, _start is provided by the standard library that in order will call main when everything is set up.